# como vincular symfony a una base de datos postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony2, symfony, postgresql-9.3

tengo un proyecto en symfony, pero me hace falta que sea con una base de datos en postgresql, pero cuando lo intento me da el siguiente error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no tengo el xampp, en la maquina solo tengo php y trabajo directamente con el servidor q genera el propio symfony. ¿Como puedo resolver este problema?

Comment: Estoy trabajando en windows, me puedes explicar como hacerlo para windows

Comment: ya lo hice y me sigue dando el mismo error, por eso publique la pregunta aqui, haber si habia q hacer algo mas

Comment: cuando probe lo hice para el pdo_pgsql y para el pgsql lo raro esta q dentro de mi php.ini estas extenciones me salen sin el .dll, no se si esto tenga algo q ver y no se si mi extension_dir apunta a la carpeta ext q es donde estan las librerias php_pdo_pgsql.dll y php_pgsql.dll, igual dentro del php.ini las extensiones no tiene puesta la palabra php_ no se si esto influye tambien

Comment: el problema es que estas usando el php de symfony que  te instala, alli hay un php que debes modificar y agregar las librerias haz un where php para ver la ruta donde esta ejecutandose el php

Comment: ya verifique el phpinfo y el php me esta cargando el driver pgsql perfecto, parece q el problema lo esta dando doctrine q cuando intento crear una entidad me dice q no encuentra el driver, sabes alguna solucion para esto

Comment: como lo hago, no se, estoy empezando con esto

Comment: en el php.ini busca pdo_psql algo asi

Comment: eso ya lo tengo hecho sin en el phpinfo se ve q esta activo, el problema esta en doctrine, no hay alguna forma de decirle de donde tiene q tomar el driver

Answer (score 2):

Primero instala el driver php-pgsql si es linux seria

```
apt-get install php-pgsql
```

Luego ve a tu ejecuta nano /etc/postgresql/9.xx/main/ph_hba.conf
y busca la linea que dice:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
```

y cambiala por:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
```

Reinicia el servicio de apache y postgresql

```
systemctl restart postgresql
systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: estoy trabajando en windows, me puedes explicar como hacerlo en windows y no tengo apache instalado trabajo directamente con el servidor de prueba de symfony

Comment: solo descomenta en el fichero php.ini  la línea que dice extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll, (solo quita el punto y coma que aparece al inicio)

Answer (score 2):

Yo tenía el mismo problema, lo solucioné de esta forma:

- en el fichero `php.ini` descomentarié la línea `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll`
- en el fichero `config.yml` en la configuración del doctrine debes tener esto:

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva!